# MongoDB "Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding \"processManagement.fork\" to false"

Tags: linux, mongodb, configuration, ubuntu-20.04

Im trying to run MongoDB in my local machine with below configuration and mongod.conf file.

Ubuntu Version - Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (FOCAL)

[image]

Below is the error im getting while starting mongodb

[image]

I tried removing MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK variable from configuration and also tried with making processManagement.fork = true.

Still its failing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what version of MongoDB you are using. We can't find any documentation related to the variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK in MongoDB documentation, but we are aware that mongoDB introduced a new startup flag ignore fork option with systemd.

You can find the JIRA links below:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-15962
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-74845

According to [this thread](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-config-override-nofork-after-upgrade-to-5-18/229218/4), systemd doesn't detect as it's running while mongod service does the job. It started from 5.0.15 towards related to the forking in systemd.

You can check the mongodb.log and system log to get a better understanding too.

Hope this helps.